# Crawl dynamic page crawl website elements

Tags: python

I am crawling through Python.

[image]

The discount price on the page above is shaded in red, and it exists in the form of text in the script tag when you search for the website developer tool.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs4
import requests as req
import json

url = 'https://www.11st.co.kr/products/4976666261?NaPm=ct=ld6p5dso|ci=e5e093b328f0ae7bb7c9b67d5fd75928ea152434|tr=slsbrc|sn=17703|hk=87f5ed3e082f9a3cd79cdd0650afa9612c37d9e8&utm_term=&utm_campaign=%B3%D7%C0%CC%B9%F6pc_%B0%A1%B0%DD%BA%F1%B1%B3%B1%E2%BA%BB&utm_source=%B3%D7%C0%CC%B9%F6_PC_PCS&utm_medium=%B0%A1%B0%DD%BA%F1%B1%B3'

res = req.get(url)
soup = bs4(res.text,'html.parser')

# json_data1=soup.find('body').find_all('script',type='text/javascript')[-4].text.split('\n')[1].split('=')[1].replace(';',"")
# data=json.loads(json_data1)
# print(data)

json_data2=soup.find('body').find_all('script',type='text/javascript')[-4].text.split('\n')
print(json_data2)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qpiT4.png)

However, if you print the code on the terminal through the code, you can see that the discount price you saw on the web browser page is printed as the normal price as shown below. How can I get that value?

The selenium module takes a long time to implement, so I want to access requests or other directions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using regular expressions will do the trick.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs4
import re
import requests as req
import json

url = 'https://www.11st.co.kr/products/4976666261?NaPm=ct=ld6p5dso|ci=e5e093b328f0ae7bb7c9b67d5fd75928ea152434|tr=slsbrc|sn=17703|hk=87f5ed3e082f9a3cd79cdd0650afa9612c37d9e8&utm_term=&utm_campaign=%B3%D7%C0%CC%B9%F6pc_%B0%A1%B0%DD%BA%F1%B1%B3%B1%E2%BA%BB&utm_source=%B3%D7%C0%CC%B9%F6_PC_PCS&utm_medium=%B0%A1%B0%DD%BA%F1%B1%B3'

res = req.get(url)
soup = bs4(res.text,'html.parser')

# json_data1=soup.find('body').find_all('script',type='text/javascript')[-4].text.split('\n')[1].split('=')[1].replace(';',"")
# data=json.loads(json_data1)
# print(data)

json_data2=soup.find('body').find_all('script',type='text/javascript')[-4].text.split('\n')
for i in json_data2:
    results = re.findall(r'lastPrc : (\d+?),',i)
    if results:
        print(results)
```

OUTPUT

```
['1310000']
```

The value that you are looking for is no longer there.

[image]

Comment: It is not the discount price in the first image. Is there any way to get the discount price?? Discount Value = 1,159,900

Comment: No because the item at the link you provided is not that price. @hanbit visit the page again... the price has changed, either that or you are providing the wrong link

Comment: If so, is there a way to get data through the requests.post method in the Fetch/XHR section of the F12 Network tab of Developer Tools? The response value of the element has "TOTAL_AMT":1159900,"MEMBER_TOTAL_AMT":1310000 values in json format.

Comment: @hanbit  The value is no longer there..  If it was there then you could just use the same method that I used to get the value that I retreived

Comment: Then, if you want to crawl the discount price (red color) shown in the URL, does it mean that it is difficult to crawl with the requests module? Is there any way to find it other than selenium?